# is there a mouse event after scrolling

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

I am currently working on a javascript project which only updates itself and the canvas on specific events like "mousedown", "mouseup", "mousemove", "wheel", "mouseout", etc. for performance reasons. If the user drags (mouse is down and mousemove event is triggered) or scrolls inside the canvas, it changes to a "transforming" state **and i need to undo that after these transforming events happen**. I use "mouseup" to trigger an update after dragging and it works fine, **but how can I trigger an update when the user *stops* scrolling?** Right now, the canvas is frozen (in "transforming" state), because there is no event that's triggered after the scroll event. I don't want to update all the time and I don't want to see the transforming state until the mouse is beeing moved (which triggers an update as well).

Comment: You can debounce the scroll event so when the user stops it gets called.

Comment: Your question could be improved by adding the relevant code segment(s).

Comment: debouncing seems most reasonable, though i never heard of it before.